# SwiftUI How to Isolate OnReceive to a Single Picker

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am building a flashcard type app and it has three pickers, the first for picking the card set, the second for picking what you would like to be shown, and the third for picking what you would like to guess (for trinary cards).

I have an .onReceive method attached to each of the pickers such that I can perform some actions when one of them has its value changed. However, changing the value of any picker calls every onRecieve method!

Here is the relevant code:

```
  VStack {
    ZStack {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        .strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
        .background(.white)
        .frame(height: pickerHeight)
      Picker(selection: $selectedTopic, label: Text(topicPickerLabel)) {
        ForEach(0 ..< topics.count) {
          Text(self.topics[$0]).tag($0)
        }
      }
      .pickerStyle(.menu)
      .disabled(topicDisabled)
      .onReceive([self.selectedTopic].publisher.first()) { (value) in
        TopicSelected(value: value) }
    }
    
    ZStack {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        .strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
        .background(.white)
        .frame(height: pickerHeight)
      Picker(selection: $shownSelected, label: Text(shownPickerLabel)) {
        ForEach(0 ..< shownChoices.count) {
          Text(self.shownChoices[$0]).tag($0)
        }
      }
      .pickerStyle(.menu)
      .disabled(shownDisabled)
      .onReceive([self.selectedTopic].publisher.first()) { (value) in
        ShownSelected(value: value) }
    }
    
    ZStack {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        .strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
        .background(.white)
        .frame(height: pickerHeight)
      Picker(selection: $guessSelected, label: Text(guessPickerLabel)) {
        ForEach(0 ..< guessChoices.count) {
          Text(self.guessChoices[$0]).tag($0)
        }
      }
      .pickerStyle(.menu)
      .disabled(guessDisabled)
    }
  }.padding(10)

func TopicSelected(value: Int) {
   if value > 0 {
      print("inside TopicSelected: \(value)")
      shownDisabled = false
   }

 }

func ShownSelected(value: Int) {
  if value > 0 {
    print("inside ShownSelected: \(value)")
    guessDisabled = false
  }

}
```

And this is the results from the print statements when I change a single value in a single picker:

```
inside ShownSelected: 7
inside TopicSelected: 7
inside ShownSelected: 7
inside TopicSelected: 7
```

How do I make it so that touching a picker calls the onRecieve attached to just that picker, and not all the others?

Comment: you could try using `.onChange` instead, on each Picker, with the appropriate selection var.

Comment: Thank you @workingdog-support-ukraine this was the correct answer!  Feel free to write it up so I can give you proper credit :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `.onChange(...)` instead of `.onReceive(...)`, on each Picker, with the appropriate selection var, to perform some actions when a specific Picker selection changes its value.